# Matlab Anonymous Function If Else

Tags: matlab, lambda, anonymous-function

In MATLAB I am trying to do a function on a cell array, but am not having much luck. I would like to create a `cellfun` which checks whether `str2double` returns `NaN` values and then perform the `str2double` on the values which aren't `NaNs`. I'm trying to use an anonymous function with an IF Else sort of statement in it but not really getting anywhere. Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
x = cellfun(@(x)~isnan(str2double(x)),str2double(x))
```

However it doesn't work, could anybody help me out?

Comment: What should be done to cells that do return `NaN` after calling `str2double` on them?

Comment: could you provide an example of that data you are trying to input.

Comment: An aside, you are using the same variable name to represent 3 different concepts here. `x` is the input, the output and also the variable of the anonymous function. I think this is likely to be very confusing. At least change the anonymous function variable name.

Comment: I'm very new to anonymous functions in MATLAB and am having trouble finding resources to tell me about it

Comment: It's just a general cell array where they are all strings but i want to convert some strings to doubles ie x = {'date','number';'12/12/12','3'}. I'd like to convert the 3 here to a double and return the cell array

Comment: @Lererferler If you are new to anonymous functions then can I suggest that you first try get this working with a `for`-loop? If you can, you should add that code to your question as well.

Comment: Do you mean using a for and if statement like, if isnan(str2double(x{i,j}) sort of thing? Because that is pretty obvious. I'm asking in order to find an elegant and efficient way of doing it as I know there is one! Lambda functions in other programming languages would work here and AFAIK anonymous functions are very similar. I just don't yet know how to use them in MATLAB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use logical indexing:

```
x = {'1', 'NaN', '2', 'NaN'}
y = str2double(x(~isnan(str2double(x))))

y =
     1     2
```

This calls `str2double` twice, so it may run a little slow if you have to do it a million times.

EDIT: as pointed out by Dan, if you want to change the cell array in place, use

```
x{~isnan(str2double(x))} = str2double(x(~isnan(str2double(x))))
```

Comment: To completely match OP's attempt this should be `x(~isnan(str2double(x))) = str2double(x(~isnan(str2double(x))))`

Comment: @Dan: good point - my solution does not change the array in place.

Comment: This would work yes thank you. I should maybe say I am asking how to get the functionality of an If Else statement in a Anonymous function more clearly, this was kind of a general example (though I am still using it). Perhaps I am just barking up the wrong tree

Answer (score 6):

Here is a nice, compact and working iif implementation:

```
iif = @(varargin) varargin{3-(varargin{1}>0)}
```

Usage:

```
iif(condition, true_value, false_value)
```

The function returns true value if the condition evaluates to true and the false_falue otherwise.

Here is a useful filter that can be applied on cells read from csv or excel file so they can be used as a numeric array. For example on an arrary Ra that was read using xlsread:

```
numeric_array = cellfun( @(x) iif(isnumeric(x) & ~isempty(x),x,NaN), Ra);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get this to work using [Loren Shure's](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/01/10/introduction-to-functional-programming-with-anonymous-functions-part-1/) inline conditional:

```
iif = @(varargin) varargin{2 * find([varargin{1:2:end}], 1, 'first')}();
```

Then you can try

```
x = cellfun(@(y)iif(~isnan(str2double(y)), str2double(y), true, y), x, 'uni', 0)
```