# case distinction within octave expression

Tags: octave

I would like to use a function that behaves by the following pseudocode:

```
f = @(x,y) if x*y > 0 then 1 else 0;
```

How can I implement this in one line in Octave?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matlab Anonymous Function If Else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36867822/matlab-anonymous-function-if-else)

Comment: Look at the most upvoted answer in the linked question (the one after the accepted answer).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try

```
f = 1*(x*y>0)
```

or

```
f = @(x,y) 1*(x*y>0)
```

Comment: `f = @(x,y) (x*y>0)` is enough.

Comment: @matzeri I think that would return logic 1 or 0, not numeric 1 or 0

Comment: There is no difference  f(2,4)/2   ans =  0.50000

Comment: @matzeri no difference since you are using `/2` to make it numeric. If you try `class(f)`, you will see the difference

Comment: I see no difference in making the conversion inside the function or when used in following calculation, except that you may not need for calculation but only for logic assessment later on.

Comment: @matzeri Yes, if you will used it along with other numeric value, then it does not affect the final result. If you want to have return value in numeric or logic type, then it matters